# Is the size of this system state backup normal

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, backup, system-state

[image]I administer a small network, 2 Windows 2003 servers with around 30 users + Exchange. The system state backup generates a 28 GB file. Is this normal? I think it's too big for just 30 users + 30 computers account.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: How big is your mailstore. If you check the selection list(s) and tally up the byte count dose it match?

Comment: Are you sure it's only a backup of the System State?

Comment: added an image, just the system state. The Exchange backup is around 39Gb. I will re-create this job, something is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake, I was appending to media, thats why it grow so big!